# Vertx service proxy code generation compilation error

Tags: java, maven, vert.x

Compilation failure with release 3.5.1
On generated service proxy, Error - unreported exception java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

generate proxy code with error on the "throw t"-

```
public void handle(Message msg) {
try {
...
}
catch (Throwable t) {
msg.reply(new ServiceException(500, t.getMessage()));
throw t;
}
}
```

Stacktrace -

```
UserAsyncServiceVertxProxyHandler.java:[339,7] unreported exception java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
/Users/admin/Documents/Development/langAppServer/vertxweb/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/bijay/langapp/web/verticles/user/UserAsyncServiceVertxProxyHandler.java:[339,7] unreported exception java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:858)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of method in the interface was throwing UnsupportedEncodingException. So code generation failed. Make sure the interface doesn't throw any checked exception, otherwise code generation fails.

Here is the method in the interface.

void generateQRUrl(User user, Handler> resultHandler) throws UnsupportedEncodingException;